# Avoid WSDL location hard coded using web.xml

Tags: java, xml, web-services, wsdl

I need to avoid hard coding wsdl location in wsimport generated files using the web.xml.

I tried this in the web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>web-service</param-name>
    <param-value>http://IP:PORT/webservice?wsdl</param-value>
</context-param>
```

but I need to get this parameter from a class that is not a servlet.

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get `web-service` parameter from a servlet, you only have to do this:

```
getServletContext().getInitParameter("web-service");
```

## Edit

You have changed your question and now you want to retrieve this value from another class that is not a servlet, so I edit my answer.

I think you have two options:

- Coupling your ws class to `ServletContext`. I mean, you can manage your code to inject the `ServletContext` into your ws class and thus get access to the param.
- Creating a properties file and using `java.util.PropertyResourceBundle` to load your param from the properties file, instead from `web.xml`.